# Firebase data upload

Tags: android

i am uploading simple data in firebase no file or image in storage i want to check if my uploading is in process so i can show user a toast on again pressing the upload button that it is already in process

```
mDatabaseRef.child(id).setValue(comp,new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){
          @Override
          public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
              Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Upload Succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are uploading this data upon a click then do the following:

1- Initialize a boolean variable and name it (isLoading) and assign it to (false)

2- When the user clicks check if (isLoading) is true or false

3- If true then show your toast

4- If false then send the request

5- Inside onComplete callback assing (isLoading) to (false) again